# P(x,y) forms with A(0,3) and B(0,-3) the vertices of a right triangle with P as the vertex of the right triangle. Find its possible coordinates.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, locus

Okay, so this is what I did; I plotted the two given coordinates:

```
   |
   A
   |
   |
---.---
   |
   |
   B
   |
```

and judging from the graph, it seems there are four possible locations...

```
   |
 1 A 2
   |
   |
---.---
   |
   |
 3 B 4
   |
```

Since it's a right triangle, that means that the possible coordinates have to either be (X, -3) or (X, 3)

Slope of AB is 0 based on 
$$
m_{ab}=\frac{(-3-3)}{(0 - 0)}=0
$$

then I could just find the slope's negative reciprocal (also 0) and substitute it into one of the formula I could use (in this instance, i chose point 1 or 2):

Since,
$$
m_{a1}=0
$$

then
$$
m_{a1}=\frac{(-3-3)}{(0-X)}
$$
$$
0=\frac{(-3-3)}{(0-X)}
$$
$$
0=\frac{(-6)}{(-X)}
$$
$$
0=\frac{(6)}{(X)}
$$

but then what? Or was this question meant to have infinite coordinates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Have you ever heard of the [Thales theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) for semi circles?

Edit after comment:

This is then a classic locus exercise. Let $P(x,y)$ denote a possible point. Then according to Pythagoras, you have

- $|\overline{AP}|^2 + |\overline{BP}|^2 = |\overline{AB}|^2$
- $|\overline{AP}|^2 = x^2 + (y-3)^2$, $|\overline{BP}|^2 = x^2 + (y+3)^2$, $|\overline{AB}|^2 = 6^2$
- $\Rightarrow$ the locus of possible points $P(x,y)$ is given by
  $$x^2 + (y-3)^2 + x^2 + (y+3)^2 = 36 \Leftrightarrow 2(x^2+y^2+9)=36 \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2 = 9$$
  This is a circle around the origin with radius $r=3$. But you need to take out $A$ and $B$ ($x \neq 0$), as $A$,$B$,$P$ form a right triangle.

Comment: Unfortunately not; my teacher has just started discussing locus, so this is all new to me.

Comment: Hopefully your teacher accepts you knowing the equation of a circe with a given radius. I added a possible solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it must be $$m_{PA}=\frac{y+3}{x}=-\frac{1}{\frac{y+3}{x}}$$ where b$$m_{PB}=\frac{y+3}{x}$$ where $m$ denotes the slope

Comment: I get that the denominator is just x because the coordinate of the two given points A and B are lying on the y-axis, and why y+3 is the numerator, but why is there a negative reciprocal of slope PA?

Comment: Since $$PA$$ and $$PB$$ are orthogonal

Comment: So $$m_1=-\frac{1}{m_2}$$